# Routing Error Ruby on Rails -- Voting system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing a voting system to my blog's comments, using the `acts_as_votable` gem.

However, I'm getting a routing error: `no route matches. missing required keys: [:id]`

```
  #routes.rb
  resources :articles do
     resources :comments do
        member do
            put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
        end
    end
  end

# comments controller
def upvote
    @comment.upvote
    redirect_to :back
end

# comments/show.html.haml
= link_to like_article_comment_path(@comment), method: :put do
   = @comment.get_upvotes.size
```

Comment: Obviously--the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `rake routes | grep like` (to fatch that route), you'll get:

```
like_article_comment PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/like(.:format)  comments#upvote
```

So you're missing the first parametar - `:article_id` in your link. Should be:

```
= link_to like_article_comment_path(@article, @comment), method: :put do
  = @comment.get_upvotes.size
```

Also add the `@article` logic in your `upvote` method.